# Automate user input into script (using ssh)

Tags: ssh, scripting

Basically I have a server that has IPMI. I need to reset this when running a script and to do this I would `ssh` into the IPMI, then I would type `cd /map1` then `reset`, and the adaptor will reset itself.

How on earth do I automate this via a script? I'm as far as ssh to the correct directory but any attempt to execute `reset` seems to reset the ssh connection and not the actual command on the adaptor/server.

I should add that using expect is not an option as it isn't installed and there's no way of installing it.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `expect` or try this ugly hackery

```
( sleep 2; echo 'cd /map1'; sleep 2; echo 'reset'; sleep 2 ) | ssh ipmiService
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @RossGray lovely. Please remember to ✔ accept the answer if it was the (best) one that worked for you